# Memory allocation to a char*

Tags: c++, c

I would like to understand why this piece of code will not crash :

```
#include<studio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
    char *a;
    a=(char *)malloc(1);
    strcpy(a, "example");
}
```

I though we are writing to memory that is not the processes' since we allocate only 1 byte for the char * and we write more than that.

Can somebody please explain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't crash because the code causes *undefined behavior*.  That can mean anything happening, including "work".

Comment: u wrote `#include<studio.h>` in your code.u should write `#include<stdio.h>`.

Comment: The code misses to prototype `malloc()`, which causes UB if `sizeof (void*)` is different from `sizeof (int)`.

Comment: @a874: Your edit significant changed the question after comments and answers had been given. This made some of them un-understandable, that why I just rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 3):

Allocate enough space for the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char * a;
    a = (char *)malloc(32);
    strcpy(a, "example");
    free(a); // don't forget to free
}
```

**Explanation:**

- You allocated 1 byte you copied 7+1 (`example` + `'\0'`).
- You tried to access memory that was not allocated.

Read articles about buffer overflow.

**Important:**

If you are not aware of the input size (now we know "example" is 7+1 bytes)
you should use `strncpy` to specify the maximum number of bytes that can be copied.

There is a function `strdup` that duplicates the string. Same as `allocation` + `strcpy`.

Comment: The code misses to prototype `malloc()`, which causes UB if `sizeof (void*)` is different from `sizeof (int)`.

Comment: working on 64 and 32 bit as well `sizeof(char *) = sizeof(void *)`

Comment: If the prototype to `malloc()` is missing `malloc()` is taken to return an `int` not a `char*`. The cast to `char*` would be applied to the `int` returned, which already lacks significant bits, typically 32. That's one of the reasons why in C `malloc()` should not be casted.

Comment: my `malloc.h` contains this: `void *__cdecl malloc(size_t _Size);`

Comment: But you do not include it, not indirectly via the standard `stdlib.h` nor directly.

Comment: No more malloc defined in *

Answer (score 2):

Your allocator may allocate small chunks of fixed size for requests below certain threshold. I wouldn't be surprised you've got 8 bytes back, so `strcpy` works without crash